# Android Firebase "storage.child()" Not Working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Thanks for your time. I want to delete an image from firebase storage

I get the image url from item.imageUrl, the url looks like this:

```
 https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ubargain-18ccc.appspot.com/o/items%2F1595598547305?alt=media&token=9a488d9d-d92a-48fa-ab0b-ff9fea2c70e2
```

The code I'm using to delete the image is:

```
 val storage = Firebase.storage.reference
 val imgRef = storage.child(item.imageUrl)
 imgRef.delete()
```

but I get this error:

```
StorageException has occurred.
Object does not exist at location.
```

the image is stored under items folder:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `child()` method expects a relative **path** to the file. You can't pass a full storage URL to the `child()` method.

Instead, use the [`getReferenceFromUrl` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/FirebaseStorage#getReferenceFromUrl(java.lang.String)):

```
val imgRef = Firebase.storage.getReferenceFromUrl(item.imageUrl)
```